# MySQL Query optimization - speed up|index use

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I have the following MySQL query that takes more than a day to execute:

```
SELECT SN,NUMBER FROM a

WHERE SN IN 
    (SELECT LOWER_SN FROM b
    WHERE HIGHER_ED  LIKE "%c1" AND LOWER_ED LIKE "%16")
AND ED LIKE "%16"
```

The subquery takes 21 seconds to run and returns 11035 rows. I have indices on a:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM a
```

> Table  Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
>
> 0 a   1   wob1    1   ED  A   756095  None    None        BTREE
>   1   a   1   wob2    1   SN  A   2268287 None    None        BTREE
>   2   a   1   wob3    1   ED  A   756095  None    None        BTREE
>   3   a   1   wob3    2   SN  A   9073150 None    None        BTREE
>   4   a   1   wob4    1   NUMBER  A   18146301    None    None    YES BTREE
>   5   a   1   wob5    1   SN  A   2268287 None    None        BTREE
>   6   a   1   wob5    2   NUMBER  A   18146301    None    None    YES BTREE

`EXPLAIN` gives:

> # id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
>
> '1', 'PRIMARY', 'a', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '18146301', 'Using where'
>
> '2', 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'b', 'index_subquery', 'cfg2', 'cfg2', '47', 'func', '6', 'Using where'

Why doesn't it use the indices? How can i speedup the query?

Comment: Using LIKE with search strings starting with a `%` cannot use indexes, as strings are indexed from their starting characters. This _might_ be one of the rarer cases where correlated subqueries can actually improve performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.SN, a.NUMBER 
FROM a
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM b
   WHERE b.LOWER_SN = a.SN
      AND b.HIGHER_ED  LIKE "%c1" 
      AND b.LOWER_ED LIKE "%16"
)
AND a.ED LIKE "%16"
```

I am not usually a proponent of correlated subqueries for a number of reasons; but since you cannot benefit from indexes, this *might* work out.

It will effectively run the subquery in the background for each and every `a` record (or if the query optimizer is helping, maybe only the `a` records matching the `a.ED LIKE` condition). Normally, this will more costly; but the `EXISTS` subquery can run much much faster than the previous subquery you had since it only has to evaluate `b` records with specific LOWER_SN values, and EXISTS gives it an "early out" when finds a single match instead of finding every match. You should index `b.LOWER_SN` to make sure the `b` records for each `a` record are identified as quickly as possible.

If the above version is still slow, it might be worth trying this:

```
SELECT a2.SN, a2.NUMBER 
FROM (SELECT a.SN, a.NUMBER FROM a WHERE AND a.ED LIKE "%16") AS a2
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM b
   WHERE b.LOWER_SN = a2.SN
      AND b.HIGHER_ED  LIKE "%c1" 
      AND b.LOWER_ED LIKE "%16"
)
```

It basically just forces the a table to be filtered on the `a.ED LIKE` condition first if the optimizer doesn't do it.